# How to show entire existing postgres database in Django admin view

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an existing PostgreSQL database and I'd like to browse it within Django's admin view. How do you make all the existing tables in a database browsable in Django's admin view?

I tried following the steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I was only able to view Groups and Users. I also read that maybe I have to edit admin.py but I'm not sure where that file would  be located and what I'd have to put in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Django which tables you want to browse in the admin view.
To manage database tables Django uses `models`. Your Django project should be divided into multiple apps and each app has its own modules such as `models.py`, `view.py`, `admin.py` etc.

So if you want to browse all the tables you need to add `admin.py` files in every app and in each `admin.py` file add the following lines to **register the model with Django's admin**.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from <your_app>.models import <your_model1>, <your_models2>
```

Now for each model that you imported add.

```
admin.site.register(<your_model1>)
admin.site.register(<your_model2>)
```

Please note that only those tables will be visible in Django admin which are managed by `Django models`. If you do not have a corresponding model for a table in your database you won't be able to view it in the admin.

To know more about the how the admin works read the Django documentation for your version of Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#discovery-of-admin-files). Also [here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models.html#configuring-the-admin-interface) is a good tutorial on configuring the admin view in Django.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I still haven't been able to view the data in my existing tables. I created a model in models.py that had the same fields as the existing table I wanted to browse. I then did [these steps](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models.html#basic-workflows) but it wasn't displayed. Is it only possible to create new models which are then added to the database (not the other way around)?

Comment: @cycloidistic : Please make sure that the table is managed by django by starting the django shell, importing your model  and by writing an ORM query like `model.objects.get(id=<some_id>)`. If table is managed by django you should be able to fetch data.